# Qt Creator failed to start gdb in latest openSUSE

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, opensuse

See that when trying to debug my program in Qt Creator "Application Output" pane:

> Debugging starts
>   Debugging has failed
>   Debugging has finished

Or freezes after

> Debugging starts

Was able to run previously. Any way to fix this or to discover the problem?

Qt Creator 3.5.1, gcc 4.8.5, gdb 7.9.1, Python 2.7.9

P.S. Hmm, works fine if "Run in terminal" unchecked or terminal changed back from konsole to xterm (works in konsole previously - weird).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine if "Run in terminal" unchecked or terminal changed back from konsole to xterm (works in konsole previously - weird).